# Taking input using function in C is not working

Tags: c, visual-studio, function

I have this silly program with my silly problem. I am a very beginner. Let me tell you what I want to do and what is happening here:

**What I want to do:** I am basically trying to make a function for input which is named here as ***inp()***. This function will ask for input using these two lines:

```
printf("Enter the Number: ");
scanf("%d", &dip);
```

When my program will get the number from the user, it will store that inside a variable, let's say ***dip*** and will use this number in our another two functions named **squarefn** and **cubefn**. I don't know what's going wrong here. But, I can't use the **inp()** properly to get the number from user.

**Why I want to use the inp() function?:** Basically, I just want to keep everything inside each function so whenever I need, I will just call my functions. I created **inp()** so that, I don't need to ask twice or type twice for input.

**What is the output?: ** It's showing some random value or trash value.

Need more information? Feel free to ask!

```
#include<stdio.h>
int squarefn(int x);
int cubefn(int cube);
int coic();
int printkor(int printkortesi);
int inp();

int main()
{
    coic();
}

int squarefn(int input)
{
    input = input * input;
    return input;
}

int cubefn(int input)
{
    input = input * input * input;
    return input;
}

int coic()
{
    int coi;
    int x;
    printf("Which one you want?\n");
    printf("1. Square\n");
    printf("2. Cube\n");
    printf("Enter here: ");
    scanf("%d", &coi);
    
    int cubed = cubefn(x);

    switch (coi)
    {
    case 1:
        // printf("Enter the Number: ");
        // scanf("%d", &x);
        inp();
        int dear = inp(x);
        squarefn(dear);
        int squared = squarefn(x);
        printkor(squared);
        break;
    case 2:
        printf("Enter the Number: ");
        scanf("%d", &x);
        cubefn(x);
        int cubed = cubefn(x);
        printkor(cubed);
        break;
    default:
        printf("Error.");
        break;
    }
}

int inp()
{
    int dip;
    printf("Enter the Number: ");
    scanf("%d", &dip);
    return dip;
}

int printkor(int printkortesi)
{
    printf("Printed: %d", printkortesi);
}
```

Comment: `inp();
        int dear = inp(x);` - You are calling this function with and without parameter.. C does not work like this. I shrongly suggest to define functions with a defines parameters list. If the don't expect parameters, then should be defineded as `foo(void)`

Comment: @EugeneSh. I tried using a parameter. But can't understand where I am doing wrong.

Comment: `int cubed = cubefn(x);` Doesn't your compiler warn you about using `x` without initializing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot of redundant code in your program, many of the statements don't do anything except taking CPU time . Read about [Function Calls](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_functions.htm) in C. Most of your doubts will be solved after a good read

```
return_type function_name( parameter list ) {
   body of the function
}
```

You have return type of `int`, to receive value of function `foo`

```
int foo(int x)
{return x*x;}
int main()
{
int y =foo(5);  //integer y takes value returned by function foo, that is 5
printf("%d\n",y); // This will print value 25
return 0;
}
```

Your code altered as below, should work now:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int squarefn(int x);
int cubefn(int cube);
int coic();
int printkor(int printkortesi);
int inp();

int main()
{
    coic();
}

int squarefn(int input)
{
    input = input * input;
    return input;
}

int cubefn(int input)
{
    input = input * input * input;
    return input;
}

int coic()
{
    int coi;
    int x;
    printf("Which one you want?\n");
    printf("1. Square\n");
    printf("2. Cube\n");
    printf("Enter here: ");
    scanf("%d", &coi);
    
    int cubed = cubefn(x);

    int dear = inp();
    switch (coi)
    {
    case 1:
        {int squared = squarefn(dear);
        printkor(squared);
        break;}
    case 2:
        {int cubed = cubefn(dear);
        printkor(cubed);
        break;}
    default:
        printf("Error.");
        break;
    }
}

int inp()
{
    int dip;
    printf("Enter the Number: ");
    scanf("%d", &dip);
    return dip;
}

int printkor(int printkortesi)
{
    printf("Printed: %d\n", printkortesi);
}
```

Edit:
Fixed it, I just noticed there was variable declaration in the switch statement. `Case` statements are only labels. This means the compiler will interpret this as a jump directly to the label. So I added `{` `}` in switch and it should work now.

Comment: @Sowmo0509 I noticed the declaration of variables in Switch statement. I have edited the response.

Comment: Thank you so much @Mohit Sharma